# Match pointer on Loudon's Algorithms

Tags: c, match, destroy

I'm here going through this book (Mastering Algorithms in C), looking for graph implementations. But he uses some notations that are not familiar to me. It's not obvious, and I tried to find if he explained it somewhere in the book, but I didn't.

When defining the type Graph, one of the struct members is

```
int   (*match) (const void *key1, const void *key2);
```

Ok, so here we have 2 generic values that are being compared? Why inside the struct? Where is this `*match function`, that doesn't appear anywhere else?

He's using this kind of declaration all the way from singly linked lists, but without any explaining I could find.

Is the `*destroy` more or less the same kind of function? I found him saying this deallocates the memory for the struct. But again, why here?

This feels like the sort of very basic and obvious question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere, and I don't really have anyone to ask.

Comment: If you mean *Mastering Algorithms with C* by Kyle Loudon, then edit the question to say that, giving a proper bibliographic reference so other people can find it. As a general principle, also cite the chapter, clause, page, and/or other information so people can locate the code you are talking about.

Comment: In this case, it seems fairly simple. `match` is a pointer to a function. The structure has a pointer to a function that compares keys. The function is not inside the structure; the pointer is. The same for `destroy`.

Comment: Also be aware of different terminology used in different contexts. A book talking about data structures and algorithms abstractly or academically may speak of  structures as having attributes, but, in a context of the C programming language, they are usually called members, as the standard uses. Not everybody following the C tag will be familiar with “attribute” in this context. Knowing your audience and communicating with your audience is important.

Comment: Look at your documentation for the standard library function `qsort()`. The 4th parameter of `qsort()` is exactly in the form of what you are asking about. `qsort()` takes a function address as a parameter while your example (should) fill that struct element with the appropriate function address.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As the book is pretty standard for C programmers and I don't think Loudon wrote another book on algorithms in C, I also thought it was obvious enough to not mention the full name of the book. And maybe you missed it, but I mentioned it is all over the book, literally. So no need for chapter and page and so on. I also never thought the function was inside the struct; but the int value is receiving the return of a function I don't know what it's doing. I'm also not a native English speaker; in Portuguese we call it "field", but it doesn't make sense in English. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Ok. Thanks for pointing a similar example. But it still didn't helped me figure out what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define a pointer to a method.
So the struct has a variable match, which should get value a method that gets 2 `const void *`.

```c
int matchGraphMyWay(const void *key1, const void *key2){
   ...
}

int main(){
   // Graph g = ...
   g.match = &matchGraphMyWay; // Assign value to the match function.
   g.match(...) // Execute the match function
}
```

Comment: Ok. But this match function compares exactly what? What is this variable key? Is it the value of the element for the given node? If it is, why is he comparing it? I never put give any value to a node without knowing what it is, like this node is 3 in this case or 5 if not. The node is either 3 or 5 and that's it. And why is it matching inside the struct and not in a separate function?